# Cannot decode arduino encoded AES-128 ECB string using php

Tags: php, arduino

I have an encrypted string using Arduino.

```
Input text => Message to be encrypted
Key as hex => 01020304050607080910111213141516
Encrypted => dba8f0f76ed0e75abc4a970b254478bd0f47a9021a8fe940a2685e4b7a8df1fe
```

I couldn't decrypt it using PHP OpenSSL.

What I've tried.

```
    $raw = "dba8f0f76ed0e75abc4a970b254478bd0f47a9021a8fe940a2685e4b7a8df1fe";
    $key = "01020304050607080910111213141516";
    $decrypt = openssl_decrypt($raw, 'AES-128-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
    var_dump($decrypt);

    string(64) "s=a����@T'Oҳ��,8��)�oGx��ݡ����*�������4f�z���N�"
```

How can I get the decrypted string as => "Message to be encrypted"

Comment: Neither `$raw` neither `$key` are "raw".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$key = "01020304050607080910111213141516";
// convert your key
$key = pack('H*',$key);

$raw = "dba8f0f76ed0e75abc4a970b254478bd0f47a9021a8fe940a2685e4b7a8df1fe";
//convert your cipertext
$raw = hex2bin($raw);

$decrypt = openssl_decrypt($raw, 'aes-128-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING | OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);

var_dump($decrypt); // Message to be encrypted
```